# Mysql performance, one table or two

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, select

I use PHP and mysql.

Let's say I have a database table with 10 000 rows. Which of the cases below it the best performance wise?

### Case 1

Two tables, `products` and `categories`.

```
SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
```

**Products**

```
id
name
category_id
```

**Categories**

```
id
name
```

### Case 2

One table, `products`, containing all the data.

```
SELECT * FROM products
```

**Products**

```
id
name
category_name
```

### Question(s)

- Which of these cases have the best performance?
- Guess, would it take long to get data with 10 000 rows with a structure like it?
- Any pitfalls with one of the cases?

From my perspective `Case 1` is the "correct" way of doing it, but I will save some developing time by using `Case 2`. Maybe performance too?

Comment: 10k rows is nothing with proper indexing. Use a seperate table even if it would be 100 millions records!

Comment: case1  is better as far as of my knowledge and my experience

Comment: I think this is a no brainer design wise. Case 1

Comment: as per @juergend you just need to use proper indexes with case1

Comment: You should always go for CASE 1. It's much more scalable and maintainable in the long run. Databases are optimized for these kind of things, so don't worry about performance at all.

Comment: case1 as many others have already mentioned.

Comment: To improve performance besides other comments, selecting actual columns instead of all will help. If you don't need to select all, select only the ones needed. You probably should have posted this in db exchange though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is the correct (i.e. SQLish) way of storing this data. It allows you to do the following:

- Validate the category names as they are inserted and updated, using standard foreign key relationships.
- Change a category name and have it affect all products.
- Include other information about a category, such as short names, long descriptions, date added, and so on.

Performance is not the main consideration. The SQL engine takes care of performance through the use of fancy join algorithms and indexes. It does this so you can structure the data in the most sensible and maintainable way for your application.

That said, which performs better depends on a number of factors (how long the category names are, how many different names there are, how wide the product record is). Differences in performance between the two scenarios are probably not at all important in getting an application to work optimally.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 is better than 2 because if you would implement case 2 you would end up with double data. By double data I mean that you would have multiple times the same value in the "category_name" field. This is bad for two reasons, first because it will slow down performance because of too many, unnecessary data (double data). The second reason is because of efficiency. Suppose you would like to change a category name like drinks to drink it would take way more time in the 2nd case than in the 1st case.
So to answer your first question, case 1 is the way to do it.

And as you can imagine by reading my answer to question one case 1 is faster than case 2 because case 2 has unnecessary data.

And your last question, like I explained in my answer of question one, one pitfall of case 2 is is you would like to change a category name you would end up with way more work than in case 1. Case 1 has by my knowledge no pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question id `database design` centric.

Now answer to your questions:

1. Which case will give the best performance?

   **Answer -** Case 1.

   **Why?**

   - It is following the basic `SQL` rule of `Normalization` which will help you in longer run.If in future you have more than 10,000 rows then it will be tedious to handle it in the single table with `redundant data`.
   - If you do `indexing` over the `key` columns, it will help you in executing `join`  queries faster over large number of rows.
   - Two separate tables will help you in reducing data `redundancy`.

   **Why not case 2?**

   There will be violation of the `Normalization` rule with the single table.Your example shows it that with the single table it will violate these rule.
2. Will it take long to get 10,000 rows with a structure like it?

   **With case 1:**  It will take a bit long time than the `Case 2` as there will be `join` queries involved.But this time will be `negligible` and can be reduced by using `indexing`  as well.

   **With case 2:** It will take bit less time than the `Case 1` but it's performance may lack due to `redundant data` or as when the number of records will grow.
3. Possible pitfalls?

   **With case 1 -**

   - You may end up writing complex `join` queries for some difficult scenario.

   **With case 2 -**

   - Data redundancy / duplication
   - Low performance in longer run
   - Poor readability

Hope this help you.